# One of the QImage constructors gives me a linker error, but another constructor doesn't?

Tags: c++, declaration

In my project I'm using QImage to save a generated picture, but when I call

```
QImage image(width, height, QImage::Format_RGB32);
```

the visual studio compiler is giving me linker errors:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall QImage::~QImage(void)" (__imp_??1QImage@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl lightTracer(void)" (?lightTracer@@YAXXZ)

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QImage::QImage(int,int,enum QImage::Format)" (__imp_??0QImage@@QAE@HHW4Format@0@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl lightTracer(void)" (?lightTracer@@YAXXZ)
```

But if I replace the code above with just a:

```
QImage image();
```

I do not get any linker errors, and compiles fine.

What's wrong here? :(

**Update:** To try and make sure Qt was functional, I tried making a QString:

```
 QString s("hello world");
```

and this worked properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a hint to this problem at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596258/newbie-problem-with-qt-c-qimage-dont-work).

I fixed the problem by including the GUI library module in Qt Project Settings->Qt Modules.

Answer (score 2):

```
QImage image();
```

This does not declare an object and does not call the default constructor.  It declares a function named `image` that has no parameters and returns a `QImage`.

This would invoke the default constructor:

```
QImage image;
```

This will probably give you a linker error as well; make sure that you are linking against whatever library `QImage` is defined in.

Comment: Right.  You need to link against the Qt library that has the definition of `QImage`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I can go about doing that? Thanks.

Comment: You need to look in the Qt documentation to find which library file that you need to link against and add that library to the "Additional Dependencies" under "Linker => General" in the Visual C++ Project Properties.  Never having used Qt, I don't know what library you need.